# EXCEL VBA Debug: Searching through the whole workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a VBA Macro for a database I have in Excel. I've got one Worksheet that stores information such as names, emails etc. *(sadly those are not consistently placed in the same columns across all worksheets, but the email adresses span from "B:F")*, this database is split into multiple worksheets. Except all those worksheets, I have also got one other worksheet ("Sheet2" in the code below) that stores all the email addresses that have assigned to my newsletter. *(The only information in this sheet are the email addresses in the "A" column).*

The VBA I'm working on should loop through all the email adresses that have subscribed to the newsletter ("Sheet2") and check if they're stored in *"the database"* - in the other sheets as well. If not, then give a warning - write *"NOTFOUND"* in the cell next to the email.

For some reason, VBA gives me a run-time error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the row:

**With Sheets(sheetIndex).Range("B:F")**.

Originally I thought that the reason for that is that I have not activated the Sheets, but I'm still getting the error.

The code I came up with so far:

```
Sub Search_for_emails()

Dim scanstring As String
Dim foundscan As Range
Dim lastRowIndex As Long
Dim ASheet As Worksheet

Set ASheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

lastRowInteger = ASheet.Range("A1", ASheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For rowNum = 1 To lastRowInteger
    scanstring = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rowNum, 1).Value
    For sheetIndex = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(sheetIndex).Activate
        If Sheets(sheetIndex).Name <> "Sheet2" Then
            With Sheets(sheetIndex).Range("B:F")
                Set foundscan = .Find(What:=scanstring, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            End With
            If foundscan Is Nothing Then
                ASheet.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = "NOTFOUND"

            Else

                ' ASheet.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = foundscan.Rows.Count

            End If
        End If
    Next
Next rowNum
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points:

- [You should avoid `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7599798)  - no need for that.
- You should always qualify things like
  `sheet` or `range`, else Excel will use the *active* workbook /
  sheet, and that is not always what you want.
- There is a difference between the `Sheets` and the `Worksheets` collection. A `Chart`-sheet, for example, has no cells and therefore no `Range`.
- You are declaring a variable `lastRowIndex` but uses `lastRowInteger`. To avoid such errors, always put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.

Change your Sub to

```
Sub Search_for_emails()

    Dim scanstring As String
    Dim foundscan As Range
    Dim lastRowIndex As Long, rowNum As Long
    Dim ASheet As Worksheet

    Set ASheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRowIndex = ASheet.Range("A1", ASheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    For rowNum = 1 To lastRowIndex
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
                With ws.Range("B:F")
                    Set foundscan = .Find(What:=scanstring, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                End With
                If foundscan Is Nothing Then
                    ASheet.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = "NOTFOUND"
                Else
                    ' ASheet.Cells(rowNum, 2).Value = foundscan.Rows.Count

                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next rowNum
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, nice explaination! If I could make a suggestion there should be an escape when `not foundscan is nothing` to avoid an unwanted "NOTFOUND". The search should go to `Next rowNum`. I just assume that is overlooked by OP here.